# How to get the last element by date of each "type" in LINQ or TSQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, t-sql

Imagine to have a table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Price](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

where ID is the identifier of an action having a certain Price. This price can be updated if necessary by adding a new line with the same ID, different Price, and a more recent date.

So with a set of a data like

ID StartDate  Price

```
1  01/01/2009 10
1  01/01/2010 20
2  01/01/2009 10
2  01/01/2010 20
```

How to obtain a set like the following?

```
1  01/01/2010 20
2  01/01/2010 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, there are several ways to say it. Here's one that uses a subquery:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Price p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
          FROM Price
         WHERE ID = p.ID
           AND StartDate > p.StartDate
       )
```

This translates fairly trivially to LINQ:

```
var q = from p in ctx.Price
        where !(from pp in ctx.Price
                where pp.ID == p.ID
                   && pp.StartDate > p.StartDate
                select pp
               ).Any()
        select p;
```

Or should I say, I think it does. I'm not in front VS right now, so I can't verify that this is correct, or that LINQ will be able to convert it to SQL.

Minor quibble: Don't use the name `ID` to store a non-unique value (the type, in this case). It's confusing.

Comment: Table column names were simplified for question clarity :)

Comment: Even though you say you've changed the column names for the purposes of the question, I thought that I'd expand on Marcelo's suggestion that ID is confusing (In case it helps other people who are looking at this question). The name 'ID' is usually used for the primary key of a table and, in this case, it isn't the primary key (It is part of a composite key, though). What it is, however, is a foreign key to the 'action' table that the question referred to, so it may be more suitable to name it something like 'ActionID'.
This is, of course, just my opinion ;-)

Comment: Tried your LINQ query. Works like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ID & StartDate will be unique:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.StartDate, p.Price
FROM Price p
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT ID, MAX(StartDate) AS LatestDate
        FROM Price
        GROUP BY ID
    ) p2 ON p.ID = p2.ID AND p.StartDate = p2.LatestDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with `LINQ to SQL`, here is an LINQ query to express what you want:

```
from price in db.Prices
group price by price.Id into group
let maxDateInGroup = group.Max(g => g.StartDate)
let maxDatePrice = group.First(g => g.StartDate == maxDateInGroup)
select
{
    Id = group.Key,
    StartDate = maxDatePrice.StartDate,
    Price = maxDatePrice.Price
};
```